# Is there a way to associate one table's an attribute to another table's any attribute in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, join, sequelize.js, associations

There is a table called Order, Order has PK (id) and an attribute (company_id).

Other table is Company_Parameter that has PK(Id) and an attribute (cid).

I want to connect these tables on Order.company_id = Company_Parameter.cid but company_id and cid are not primary keys.

I have set an association like this in sequelize:

Order.hasMany(companyParameters, {
foreignKey: 'cid',
targetKey: 'company_id',
});
companyParameters.belongsTo(Order, {
foreignKey: 'cid',
targetKey: 'company_id',
});

but these association run:

ON `Order`.`id` =
`companyParameters`.`cid`;

I want to run

ON `Order`.`company_id` =
`companyParameters`.`cid`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `hasMany` you should use the `sourceKey` option to indicate other model's key and not `targetKey` one.

```
Order.hasMany(companyParameters, { foreignKey: 'cid', sourceKey: 'company_id', });
```